# How can I develop an MP3 cutter android application?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. Don't know much about android development!!
i haven't tried anything as i have no idea where to start with 
Can anyone post sample code for mp3 cutter . it would be great help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking training courses on Android, and then giving it a go yourself. Try easy things, such as designing the UI or making menus. Try putting Shared Preferences to use. Try making a settings dashboard. Try whatever you would like.

Another thing to note is that the code you are asking for is taking someone else's time, which is valuable. The purpose of this site is not to have others do the work for you. Look at other posts to see how others have given a shot at it, then they post THEIR sample code for others to help with. With what you have given us, there isn't much we can do for you.

Don't take this harshly- just keep trying. Developing can be daunting at first, but we encourage you to keep trying! If you are not familiar with programming, start with Java courses, such as [sololearn](http://sololearn.com). [Udacity](http://udacity.com) has Android-specific courses as well. There are many free courses.

As you get more familiar with Android, you'll also learn how to phrase your questions better. Telling us that you are new does help us know how to phrase it, but you are very vague about what you are looking for. I have no idea what an "mp3 cutter" is. I could guess, but when I am scrolling through the list of questions so I can help people, I would normally just pass it by.

I hope this helps you get started!